# Conditional logic in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Using [this example](https://docs.servicerocket.com/salesforce-jira/administrator-guide/automating-your-integration/automatic-jira-issue-creation-and-push-updates-in-the-same-trigger) as reference:

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter) {
        JCFS.API.createJiraIssue('10000', '10002');
    }
    if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter) {
        JCFS.API.pushUpdatesToJira();
    }
}
```

I have a custom field I want to check called `boolean__c` before running. I was expecting to be able to do something like this:

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter && boolean__c=true) {
        JCFS.API.createJiraIssue('10000', '10002');
    }
    if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter && boolean__c=true) {
        JCFS.API.pushUpdatesToJira();
    }
}
```

So that it will only run if `boolean__c` is true. What is the correct way to add this logic?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (after insert, after update) {
    if (Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter && trigger[0].boolean__c=true) {
        JCFS.API.createJiraIssue('10000', '10002');
    }
    if (Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isAfter && trigger[0].boolean__c=true) {
        JCFS.API.pushUpdatesToJira();
    }
}
```

but it will check only 1st element. OK when you edit 1 case at a time in UI, not so OK when you mass edit something.
Ideally you'd create some `List<Case> scope = new List<Case>();`, loop through the `trigger.new` and if true - add to the list. Then call your function only on the records that actually need it.

You can't do it without changing the functions, they take no parameters so looks like they operate directly on trigger.new. That's bit crappy, no easy way to reuse them. You'd have to modify them a bit to accept `List<Case>` (or maybe more, depends on their internal implementation, do they use trigger.oldMap too for example)